# How to unit test if an activity has been changed on Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I would like to test if my method "OnClick" that redirect me to another activity is working. But I have no idea how to do it in a unit test..

```
public void onClickManageServiceButton(View view){ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceManagement.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Robolectric to test that.

Add the testImplementation in the gradle for Robolectric
http://robolectric.org/getting-started/

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) 
public class ACTUAL_ACTIVITYTest {

@Test
public void clickingLogin_shouldStart ServiceManagementActivity() {
    WelcomeActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(ACTUAL_ACTIVITY.class);
    activity.onClickManageServiceButton(null);

    Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, ServiceManagement.class);
    Intent actual = shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application).getNextStartedActivity();
    assertEquals(expectedIntent.getComponent(), actual.getComponent());
} }
```

where ACTUAL_ACTIVITY is the activity where you have the method onClickManageServiceButton.

Trick: "Press CMD + SHIFT + T" in the activity class and you will have a quick action to create a test for that activity

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the [Espresson Intents API](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents):

In your test, set up an IntentsTestRule that will record intents being fired.

```
@Rule public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> intentsTestRule =
    new IntentsTestRule<>(MyActivity.class);
```

In your test, launch your activity, trigger the method under test, and assert:

```
@Test
public void onClickManageServiceButton() {
    // By default the rule launch your activity, so it's running by the time test starts

    // Assuming the method to test is on your activity under test...
    // You many need to find a View or mock one out to pass to the method.
    mIntentsTestRule.getActivity().onClickManageServiceButton(null);

    // Espresso will have recorded the intent being fired - now use the intents
    // API to assert that the expected intent was launched...
    Intents.intended(hasComponent(ServiceManagement.class.getName()));
}
```

Check the [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/intent/Intents) and [IntentMatchers](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/intent/matcher/IntentMatchers) class references for more on what you can do assert intents are fired.

Hope that helps!